# Mongodb schema design referencing confusion

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nosql

Imagine I want to build a book library system, I have collection of `book` and `book_category`. Should I put `user_id` into `book_category`?

By having `book_category_id` in book collection, I'm able to get `category` of each book, but what if I want to get all `category`? I should have the `user_id` inside `book_category` collection as well right? It seems to me every collection I must put `user_id` as reference.

```
book
====
id
name
price
book_category_id 
user_id

book_category
====
id 
name
user_id //confusion here
```

Answer (score 0):

The way i would design would be embedded the book_category inside the book. The book category is going to be a small number of distinct names. There is not much going to there.

When you want to get all the categories available, you could run aggregation on the mongodb to get the result. This operation i am sure you are not going to perform very often and mostly for internal purposes.

Comment: `there is not much going there`. Actually the user can add category's, including name, images, order etc.. there are quite a lot of things there.